# More Assembly to C

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

I am given the following Assembly and must translate it into C

```
.global test
.type test, @function

test:
pushl %ebp           //setup
movl %esp, %ebp      //setup
pushl %ebx           //setup
movl 8(%ebp), %edx   //tx = first argument
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx  //ty = second argument
movl $1, %eax        //num = 1
cmpl %ecx, %edx      //compare tx:ty
jge .L3              //jumps to end of function if >=

.L6
leal (%edx, %ecx), %ebx    // t1 = tx+ty
imull %ebx, %eax           // eax = eax*ebx
adll %edx,%ecx             // t2 = ty + t1
cmpl %edx, %ecx            // compare ty:tx
jg .L6                     // loops back 

.L3
popl %ebx
popl %ebp
ret
```

I came up with the following C code:

```
int test(int *x, int *y){
int tx = *x;
int ty = *y;
int num = 1;

if (tx > ty)
 return num;`
else{
do{
int t1 = tx + ty;
num *= t1;
int t2 = ty + t1;
}while(ty>tx)

return num;
```

Can anyone tell me if this translation is right?
I added the comments next to each assembly instruction to demonstrate what I believe it does

Comment: Have you tried finding out if your translation is correct?

Comment: The negative reactions are coming from followers of the C tag. Although you *are* translating to C, the question is more interesting to folks that follow the assembly and reverse-engineering tags. In the future, be more careful when selecting tags.

Comment: @fuzxxl I am trying to just do this all by hand because that is what I need to be able to do, so no I have not ran it in C.

Comment: Note there's also a [Codereview Stack](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and maybe the [Reverseengineering Stack] (http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) might be suitable too (look into them and see if it fits good)

Answer (score 1):

The translation is not correct. The line

```
movl 8(%ebp), %edx
```

takes an argument from the stack and places it in the `edx` register. There is no dereferencing involved, at least at the C level. At the assembly level `ebp` *is* dereferenced, but only to retrieve an item from the stack.

Which is to say that these lines

```
int test(int *x, int *y){
    int tx = *x;
    int ty = *y;
    int num = 1;
```

should simply be

```
int test(int x, int y){
    int num = 1;
```

I leave the rest as an exercise for the reader.